# Using booleans in equations (C)

Tags: c

Simply put, I want to do something along the lines of:

```
int a = 6.;
int b = 10 * (1 + (a==0));
```

Such that `b=10` if `a!=0`, or `b=20` if `a==0`. This particular format doesn't work, is there a way that does without having an extra if statement?

Comment: Readability aside, how did it not work? I got the correct results for your use cases.

Comment: Who cares if it is more readable? Don't do premature optimisations, concentrate on readbility and leave code generation to the compiler. As a sidenote: Why do you assign a `double` constant to an integer?

Comment: What *exactly* "*doesn't work*"? *sigh*

Comment: `6.` -> `6` and it works. The more interesting part is - why do you want to do it like this.

Comment: Ah, just force of habit, working with doubles in python. Not sure why this didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ternary operator

```
int b = a ? 10: 20;
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre; But it's really not an `if` statement :)

Comment: Thanks, this'll do for what i need :)

Comment: @Dant - Not only will it do what you need, but at least on GCC it will produce the exact same machine code, without having other people scratching their head once they get a glimpse of your code.

Comment: Actually, it's the reverse... `int b=a?20:10`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: it must be noted that non-optimized assembly is pretty much meaningless to compare in general...

Comment: @MatteoItalia - I'll be very surprised if turning optimizations on will cause the two function versions to diverge. I'd be even more surprised if it doesn't end up with one version calling another.

Comment: @StoryTeller: hence the "in general"; as could be imagined, in the optimized version the branch disappears completely and both versions boil down to loading `20` into a register before calling `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 6;
int b = 10 * (2 - (a != 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or withouth conditionals

```
int a = 123;
int b = 10 * (1 + !a);
```

Negating `a` will give `1` if a is `0`, and `0` if it is anything else.